# CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH troubles

Tags: php, cakephp, hosting

My CakePHP website was working perfectly for months, until I tried accessing it today, I got the following error:

```
Warning: include(Cake/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/corneenm/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 82

Warning: include(Cake/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/corneenm/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 82

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Cake/bootstrap.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/corneenm/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 82

Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /home/corneenm/public_html/app/webroot/index.php on line 91
```

I recently bought another hosting package from the same company, but the two do not seem to be related. I can't seem to figure out what might be going wrong.

Also: When copying the site to localhost, it still works like a charm... What can I do?

Comment: Did you clear the cache after copying your app? Always do so to flush the hardcoded paths in the cache files.

Comment: I will try that. However, the version on the server suddenly stopped working (without moving).. The version I then copied to my localhost (from the "not working" server) worked fine on localhost..

Comment: Check around line 82 of your index.php file. It would appear that [the call to ini_set](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/webroot/index.php#L88) fails, and can be corrected by identifying why the ini_set call doen't work or simply by defining the mentioned constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you all for the feedback... I have finally found a solution, if someone has the same problem as I had, this is what I have done to fix it. On line 82 in Index.php I changed the following:

```
if (!include ('Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php'))
```

to:

```
if (!include (ROOT . DS . 'lib'. DS .'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php'))
```

I still have no clue what caused the problem, but for some reason, the original line stopped functioning. I am assuming the hosting company might have changed something on their side. Just glad it's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, differences among environments are most often caused by two things: differences in OS case sensitivity or  differences in apache config, including .htaccess.

That said, if you haven't changed anything, I would first clear all files in the tmp/cache directory (leave the folders).  One final thing to check would be file permissions.  That is all I can think of at the moment. Good luck.

Comment: tmp files are not relevant to an error so early in a request.

Answer (score 0):

Please check all the .htaccess files in your cakephp code...examples are below

/var/www/app/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/app/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: how is the php include path going to be affected by .htaccess files?

Comment: Because whenever your hosting environment changes, the first check should be .htaccess because all the paths are decided by apache from .htaccess, and as your code is working perfectly fine at local environment then you must check your .htaccess files of CakePHP website. And in my experience working with CakePHP I have seen include path is mostly affected by .htaccess file only. Please check them once and hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: I'd be quite happy to be proven wrong, but that sounds like a wild guess; especially in light of `My CakePHP website was working perfectly for months` - I.e. the environment may have changed, but the application files probably haven't.