# CakePHP core could not be found

Tags: php, cakephp

[Website](http://trace.pk/) given error like as bellow. its build using cakephp. Can you help me

```
Fatal error: CakePHP core could not be found. Check the value of CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in APP/webroot/index.php. It should point to the directory containing your /cake core directory and your /vendors root directory. in /home/tracepk/public_html/webroot/index.php on line 0
```

Comment: Please add more details to regenerate or steps you have taken to do this, so we can help you properly.

Comment: Did you not follow the documentation? How did you use composer to install the core?

Answer (score 0):

View [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773531/cake-core-include-path-troubles) solution and provide for analyze content of your file index.php